# google enchanced ecommerce check out product parent id number or the individual child number?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, parent-child, checkout

with google enhanced eCommerce do I send the product parent id number or the individual child number (size/color - gtin) at checkout?

For instance I have a product of #A12345 in color Blue size Small.
The ParentID is #A12345 but the ChildID combination of color/size is #596847358

I want to be able to link back the analytics data of my checkouts to adwords/merchant center which use both ParentID and ChildID but require tracking on GTIN (ChildID) level.

Should I use the ParentID or ChildID to relate the most information accurately? 
Used at the Purchase Step :: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent id as id and child id as variant.